# Implementation of generic SOAP client using gSOAP

Tags: c++, web-services, wsdl, gsoap

Is there any clear documentation or samples to implement Generic SOAP Client using gSOAP as they implement the online version of it [here](http://www.soapclient.com/SoapTest.html)?

Comment: Are you serious? What do you want? This is not a real question.

Comment: I just want simple code or class using gsaop library so I can query the Web service for its WSDL and return me the available method names, arguments of the methods and their data types.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK gsoap "only" generats a stub rather then allow you to browse the available methods at runtime. 
Take a look at the [Quick Start Guide.](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html)

Perhaps you could be more specific?